# RMS Value of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, normed-spaces

Let $x$ be a block vector with two vector elements $x=(a,b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are vectors of size $n$ and $m$, respectively.

How do I express $rms(x)$ in terms of $rms(a)$, $rms(b)$, $m$ and $n$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the conventional definition of the [RMS value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) of a finite dimensional vector,
\begin{align*}
x_\text{RMS} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n+m}\sum_{i=1}^{n+m}x_i^2} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n+m}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 + \sum_{j=1}^m b_j^2\right)} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n+m}(na_\text{RMS}^2 + mb_\text{RMS}^2)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, how would i also be able to do this with $avg(x)$ as well?

Comment: Also, just wondering for the last line, wouldn't it be $na_{RMS}$ not $na^{2}_{RMS}$

Comment: Since $a_\text{RMS} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}$, we have that $n a_\text{RMS}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2$, so when making the substitution in the last equality, we need the square on $a_\text{RMS}$.